# How can I prevent a slipped disk?

Tags: injury-prevention

I went to a massage/body therapy place while on holiday for a massage and was told by the guy that I have the beginnings of a slipped disk. They didn't speak English very well but I believe they said it was either the c6 or c7 one if that makes a difference.

What can I do to prevent the disk from slipping out?

I recently started to do weightlifting regularly (bench press, rows and deadlift). Should I stop doing these, especially the deadlift since it involves the back?

Are there exercises or stretches or anything else that I should or should not do in order to prevent/fix this?

The person told me that it may be because of sleeping or sitting. What are the best ways to sleep for this problem? Would sitting up tall, with back straight and shoulders back while at work (desk job) or while driving be better?

Comment: This is absolutely not something you should get advice for over the internet. You have no guarantee that the advice comes from someone qualified, and besides, this is something that should be diagnosed by a doctor. Please go see your doctor, and in the meantime, refrain from any heavy exercise.

Comment: I'd be very careful with cervical (neck) disks if I were you.